How to load one file at a time in informatica powercenter if file size is large
I have 10 flat files of the same structure which I have to load using informatica powercenter.
I can load them using file repository concept but my files size is large so I want to know is there any way by which we can load one file at a time and after getting the confirmation we can start with the consecutive files so even if the workflow fails in between we can see from the session logs till which file the load has been completed.
Any leads would be helpful.
Thanks

Have you tried indirect file loading process where you

list the file names in a list_file using a pre-process command.
use the list_file to load using indirect loading in session

This loads one file at a time and in the session log it shows which file is currently loaded. But please note, if a file has some issues like data type mismatch/length mismatch, the session log is normally logs every details so it tends to be huge. its difficult to gather which file caused the problem.

Hi,
I have tried this but is there any way to get a confirmation mail after each file is loaded ?

Sure there is! Set a local variable in an expression to detect file change and based on the value send the row to the notification pipeline built according to your needs (a log file, rest service, email notification service, etc.)
